# Write and append Spark streaming data to a text file in HDFS

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs, spark-streaming

I am creating a spark scala code in which I am reading a continuous stream from MQTT server.
I am running my job in yarn cluster mode. I want to save and append this stream in a single text file in HDFS.

I will be receiving stream of data after every 1 second. So I need this data to be appended in single text file in HDFS.

Can any one help.

Comment: You cannot have multiple tasks writing to the same HDFS file at the same time. So why use Spark?

Comment: possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389594/is-it-possible-to-append-to-hdfs-file-from-multiple-clients-in-parallel
may also be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997137/append-data-to-existing-file-in-hdfs-java

Comment: For me data is over writing to latest stream . I am saving dstream like:  val lines = MQTTUtils.createStream(ssc,brokeraddress,topic)

lines.foreachRDD{rdd =>        
rdd.saveAsTextFile("rddoutput")}. I am getting data after every .5 second. So i need to save all data. But "lines" is loading with latest Dstream

Comment: @Arpit hi ,have done it.i am having similar kind of  architecture can u help

Comment: @Arpit Did you get it solved?

Answer (score 2):

Use data frame and use mode Append 
This will append the data every time new record comes.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(context)
import sqlContext.implicits._

stream.map(_.value).foreachRDD(rdd => {
    rdd.foreach(println)
    if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
        rdd.toDF("value").coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).save("C:/data/spark/")
        // rdd.saveAsTextFile("C:/data/spark/")
    }

})
```

Comment: Can you just explain how this line works 

_rdd.toDF("value").coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).json("C:/data/spark/")_

Answer (score 1):

@Amrutha J Raj

```
rdd.toDF("value").coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).json("C:/data/spark/")
```

This means, `RDD` will convert to `DF` and we have used `coalesce(1)` so it will have only one file if you wont use that then spark may generate multiple files so with this it will restrict to only one and our write mode is Append so it will be appending to the existing file and inn json format.